# "Undefined reference" error when using an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have instructions to use a pointer of a pointer as an array of pointers and this is what I have:

```
className **wordArray;
wordArray = new className*[wordCount];
ifstream fileInput;
fileInput.open(fileDir);
while (fileInput >> wordInput)
{
    wordArray[countNumber] = new className(wordInput.c_str());
    countNumber++;
}

class className
{
public:
    className(const char *word);
    ~className();
};

className::className(const char *word)
{
    char wordArray[strlen(word)];
    strcpy(wordArray, *word);
}
```

My problem occurs when it compiles, or tries to. It says that there is an "undefined reference" to the class. The constructor for the class is supposed to take a `const char*` and I have tried a few other things to no avail.

Comment: This is not C. removing the tag.

Comment: [What is undefined reference and how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can more easily reproduce the problem if/as needed.

Comment: Apart from the obvious problem of writing what is supposed to be C++ code as if it were C, you have a serious bug here: `char wordArray[strlen(word)];` - this should be: `char wordArray[strlen(word) + 1];`.

Answer (score 1):

undefined reference means that some function or variable was declared but not implemented. In this case you need to provide implementation of constructor, e.g.:

```
className::className(const char *word)
{
    // do something here...
}
```

And the same for destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `Undefined reference` error because you are missing the implementation of `className`'s constructor and destructor. Both can be empty, but must exist either inline, or as separate functions.

Inline:

```
class className {
public:
  className(const char *word) {}
  ~className() {}
};
```

Separate functions:

```
class className {
public:
  className(const char *word);
  ~className();
};

className::className(const char *word) {}
className::~className() {}
```

For me, this minimal working example compiles:

```
#include <string>

class className {
public:
  className(const char *word) {}
  ~className() {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  className **wordArray;
  std::string wordInput = "test";
  int wordCount = 0;

  wordArray = new className*[wordCount];
  wordArray[0] = new className(wordInput.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I realized I had made about the stupidest mistake I have ever made. I forgot to include the other .cpp file in the command to compile it. Although, now that I did, I have an error that says "expected unqualified-id before 'const'" and "expected ')' before 'const'".

Comment: The problem seems to not be related to this question. Please search for questions alike, and if you don't find any matching your problem, ask a new question together with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).